# Is $\frac{1}{\left|x\right|^\alpha}$ integrable at infinity for any $\alpha$ in dimension $\geqq 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I think it is easy to calculate the following: $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^\alpha} dx= \begin{cases} + \infty & \text{for } \alpha \geqq 1 \\ 
M < \infty & \text{for } \alpha < 1\end{cases}$$
and 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^\alpha} dx= \begin{cases} + \infty & \text{for } \alpha \leqq 1 \\ 
N < \infty & \text{for } \alpha > 1\end{cases}\text{.}$$
We can then generalise this to $d$-dimensions. I denote by $B_r$ the ball of radius $r$ centred at $0$  and use the formula
$$\int_{A_{r_1}^{r_2}} \frac{1}{\left|x\right|^\alpha}\,dx =(\left|\partial B_{r_2}\right|- \left|\partial B_{r_1}\right|)\int_{r_1}^{r_2} \frac{1}{r^\alpha} r^{d-1} dr$$where ${A_{r_1}^{r_2}} = \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^d \,\colon r_1 < \left|x\right| < r_2\}$ is an annulus. I then found that around $0$ we are in a similar situation as in $d = 1$:
$$\int_{B_1} \frac{1}{\left|x\right|^\alpha} dx= \begin{cases} + \infty & \text{for } \alpha \geqq d \\ 
< \infty & \text{for } \alpha < d\end{cases}$$ but I also found that (in $d\geqq 2$) we have $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{A_{1}^{R}} \frac{1}{\left|x\right|^\alpha}\,dx = \infty \text{ for all } \alpha\text{.}$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I sorted it: I think what I have said is wrong! I'll leave the question here because it may be useful for others:

For $d > 1$ we have

$$\begin{align}\int_{A_r^R} \left|x\right|^{-\alpha} \, dx &= \int_r^R \int_{\partial B_s} s^{-\alpha} \,\mathrm d\sigma \,\mathrm ds \\ &= \left|\partial B_1\right| \int_r^R  s^{-\alpha+d-1} \,\mathrm ds \\ &= \left|\partial B_1\right|\begin{cases}\log\left(\frac{R}{r}\right) & \text{if } \alpha=d \\ \frac{R^{d-\alpha} - r^{d=\alpha}}{d-\alpha} & \text{if }\alpha \not = d\end{cases} \\ &\to\begin{cases} \begin{cases} \text{const. }R^{d-\alpha} & \text{as } r \to 0 \\ +\infty& \text{as } R \to \infty  \end{cases} & \text{if } \alpha < d  \\ \begin{cases} +\infty&\text{as } r \to 0 \\ \text{const. } r^{d-\alpha}& \text{as } R \to \infty\end{cases}  & \text{if } \alpha > d  \end{cases} \end{align}$$

Comment: What is $n$? Do you mean $d$ instead? And if $\alpha$ is big and positive, why does it not overcome the rest at infinity?

Comment: oh yeah $n$ is $d$ - copied it wrong